# Changing a DIV on hover of an anchor link

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to change a div when hovering ANY anchor link within a document. It only works when it's not inside any other container.

Is there anyway to have this work within a usual page layout (inside body>divs)?

```css
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #0081ff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition:
    background .35s ease,
    box-shadow .35s ease,
    transform .35s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
  
.circle:hover ~ #circle {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #E91E63;
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div> <!--If you remove this DIV, it works-->
<a href="#" class="circle">Circle</a>
</div>

<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: learn about `~`...:https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @לבנימלכה I've been looking at this page - as helpful as it is, none of the selectors seem to work for me...

Comment: https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling

Comment: In CSS you can only select **forward** and **deeper** into the tree, never upward or backward.

Comment: @gromey What you want cannot be done with CSS.

Comment: Ah I see - maybe I can look at Javascript to detect mouseover event on addClass

Answer (score 0):

```css
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #0081ff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition:
    background .35s ease,
    box-shadow .35s ease,
    transform .35s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
  
.circle:hover ~ #circle  {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #E91E63;
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div  class="circle"> <!--If you remove this DIV, it works-->
<a href="#">Circle</a>
</div>

<div id="circle"></div>
```